# Flutter - background process - how best to package a process that can started in multiple ways

Tags: flutter

I have a question about how best to structure a background process in a Flutter mobile app that can be triggered in a number of ways.

This background process has to run a web API call, or series of web API calls. The process will take 1 to 5 seconds to complete.

I want the process to be initiated when any of the following occurs:

- When the app first starts
- When the user initiates a 'refresh' by clicking on a button in the UI
- Every hour

Any suggestions on how to structure this in a Flutter app?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service

It can run code in background and/or in foreground either on iOs and Android.

Background and foreground are run in isolate, so you should use mechanism provide by package to exchange data between your application and background/foreground.